# sorting positive and negative integers through two integer arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

We gave the following string:

```
int [] array = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87}.
```

There must be two rows, one for storage and the other positive elements for the negative elements of string array, and extracting the necessary logic that will perform the appropriate elements and placing them in the appropriate thread.

In other words, in the line array that is given is to be obtained all the positive elements and be placed in a separate row. Also, all the elements to be obtained and the negative to be placed in a separate row.

You also need to determine the number of duplicates in the string array.

Of course, it is necessary functionality written to be applicable to any number of integers.  But MY teacher said that my code doesn't have a target row and He gave me  an example: Target strings are two additional rows you will place isolated positive and negative values. For example, if you have a string:

```
int arr = {1,2,3,4, -1, -2, -3, -4}
```

then the target ranges will be:

```
int pos = {1,2,3,4}
int hc = {-1, -2, -3, -4}
```

of course, this should make it programmable and not hard coded, as in this example.   Now how can I improve my code?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int array1[]= {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};

    System.out.println("Array 1 :");

    Arrays.sort(array1);

    for (int positive: array1) {

        if (positive >= -1)
            System.out.println("Positive numbers :" + positive+ "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Array 2 :");

        for (int negative: array1) {
            if (negative >= -1) {

            }else{ System.out.println("Negative numbers :" +negative);
            }

        } 
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length -1; i++) { 
             if (array1[i + 1 ] == array1[i]) {
                 System.out.println("Duplicate element found :" + array1[i]);
                 i = i + 1;

             }          

        }

    }           
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i have understood your question correctly, you want to make new arrays containing the positive and negative numbers,

Using your variable names i would go for something like this solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Declare variables
    int[] array1 = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87}, pos, hc;
    int positive = 0, negative = 0;

    // Check how many positive and/or negative numbers
    for (int i : array1)
    {
        if (i >= 0)
        {
            positive++;
        } else 
        {
            negative++;
        }
    }

    // Make exact size arrays
    pos = new int[positive];
    hc = new int[negative];

    // Reset variables for new purpose
    positive = 0;
    negative = 0;

    //Put numbers in correct array
    for (int i : array1)
    {
        if (i >= 0)
        {
            pos[positive] = i;
            positive++;
        } else
        {
            hc[negative] = i;
            negative++;
        }
    }

    // Display arrays
    System.out.print("Starter array: ");
    for (int i: array1)
    {
        System.out.print(" " + i);
    }

    System.out.print("\nPositive array: ");
    for (int i: pos)
    {
        System.out.print(" " + i);
    }

    System.out.print("\nNegative array: ");
    for (int i: hc)
    {
        System.out.print(" " + i);
    }

}
```

This outputs:

Starter array:  12 23 -22 0 43 545 -4 -55 43 12 0 -999 -87

Positive array:  12 23 0 43 545 43 12 0

Negative array:  -22 -4 -55 -999 -87

Comment: and where a put     for  duplicate numbers   for (int i = 0; i < array1.length -1; i++) { 
            if (array1[i + 1 ] == array1[i]) {
                System.out.println("Duplicate element found :" + array1[i]);
                i = i + 1;
                    
                }          

            }

Comment: I'm sorry, your question was regarding sorting an array into positive and negative arrays. If you wish to also detect duplicates, i would write a second for-loop within the sorting loop that counted how many times the value was represented within the array. And then save values represented more than once to a fourth array.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 int array1[]= {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};

 System.out.println("Array 1 :");

 Arrays.sort(array1);
 ArrayList<Integer> pos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 ArrayList<Integer> neg = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 for (int num: array1){
  if (num>= 0)
       pos.add(num);
   else
       neg.add(num);
}
 System.out.println();

 if(pos.size()>0)
 {
 int[] positive = new int[pos.size()];
 positive = pos.toArray(positive);
 pos=null;
 for (int num: positive)
      System.out.println("Positive numbers :" + num+ "\t");
 }

 if(neg.size()>0)
 {
 int[] negative = new int[neg.size()];   
 negative = pos.toArray(negative);
 neg=null;
 for (int num: negative)
      System.out.println("Negative numbers :" + num+ "\t");
 }

for (int i = 0; i < array1.length -1; i++) { 
    if (array1[i + 1 ] == array1[i]) {
        System.out.println("Duplicate element found :" + array1[i]);
        i = i + 1;

        }          

    }
```

Comment: i tried but  give me a error  positive = pos.toArray(pos);    negative = pos.toArray(negative);    ok thanks  i try to fix  what you made

Answer (score 0):

```
   sepratePositiveNegative(int[] arr) {
        int size  = arr.length;
        int k =0;
        for(int i =0;i <size; i++){
            int temp = 0;
            if(arr[i]<0) {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[k];
                arr[k] = temp;
                k++;
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
            }
        }
```